# Select months between two dates

Tags: c#, excel, datetimepicker

I am trying to create a form which will take attendance data from a database and transfer to a excel sheet to print out.

I have created the form and with two datetimepickers I have managed to get the month to begin the travel claim and the month I want to claim too.

I am struggling with separating  this into individual months so that I can use the individual months to intigrate the database.

so far I have

```
    if (TodateTimePicker.Value.Date <= FromdateTimePicker.Value.Date)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("End Date must be after Start Date");
    }
    else
    {
        fromDate = FromdateTimePicker.Value.Date;
        toDate = TodateTimePicker.Value.Date;

        fromDate = (fromDate.AddDays(1 - fromDate.Day));

        toDate = (toDate.AddDays(1 - toDate.Day)).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
    }
```

I also have the database command I want to use

```
            com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT count(*), FROM Attendances WHERE year([Attendance_Date]) = ? GROUP BY [Person] ORDER BY count(*) DESC", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
            com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", month));
            com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", p.ID));
```

My real question is how to get the 1st of each month and the last date of each month between the two dates selected?

Comment: So you need the months between FromDate and ToDate?

Comment: Yes, I need the months between the two dates, preferably for each month to have the date for the 1st of the month and the last date in the month

Comment: @user3408148 Ryan, does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: So you expect something like:
- Initial date = 2015-01-01
- Final date = 2015-03-14

- Result:
- 01-01
- 01-31
- 02-01
- 02-28
- 03-01

Comment: @carlosherrera, exactly but with the end of the last month aswell

Comment: And then... you will use them in the query you wrote? For example:

SELECT count(*), FROM Attendances WHERE year([Attendance_Date]) = '01-01' GROUP BY [Person] ORDER BY count(*) DES

??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution where I calculated the number of months between the two dates, then ran through a loop to add the number of months to the start date to give me the first and last day of each month between the two original dates, probably not the neatest way but it works exactly as I planned.

int months = ((toDate.Year - fromDate.Year) * 12 + toDate.Month - fromDate.Month) + 1; // find the munber of months between the two dates and add one

```
        DateTime dateofclaim = new DateTime(); // define dateofclame to a new date  

        for (int i = 0; i < months; i++) // for each month run the code below, this will first run the fromDate then add a month until it gets to the toDate
        {
            dateofclaim = fromDate.AddMonths(i); // add one month to the start date

            claimfromDate = (dateofclaim.AddDays(1 - dateofclaim.Day)); // calculate the first date of the month

            claimtoDate = (dateofclaim.AddDays(1 - dateofclaim.Day)).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1); // calculate the last day of the month

            OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT sum([sum]) FROM Attendance WHERE ([Attendance_Date]) >= ? AND ([Attendance_Date]) <= ? AND [Person] = ?", Program.DB_CONNECTION); // count the total attendances in the month
            com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", claimfromDate));
            com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", claimtoDate));
            com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", person.ID));

            OleDbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader(); // start reader  

            if (dr.Read()) // if a result is returned
            {
                try
                {
                    int attendance = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetDouble(0)); // this is how many attendances have been counted for the selected month

                    ws.get_Range("B" + row.ToString()).Value2 = dateofclaim.ToString("MMM yyyy"); // print the Month of the clame into Colum B and row 83 then adding one for each following month
                    ws.get_Range("I" + row.ToString()).Value2 = attendance.ToString(); // print the number of attendances into Colum B and the respective row
                    row++; // add one to the row so next time this runs the data will be on the next row 
                }
                catch // if nothing as returned from the database then add the month and 0 in the attendance colum
                {
                    ws.get_Range("B" + row.ToString()).Value2 = dateofclaim.ToString("MMM yyyy");
                    ws.get_Range("I" + row.ToString()).Value2 = "0";
                    row++;
                }
            }
            dr.Close(); // close the database reader
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the 2 easiest ways I've found :

```
private int IntervalInMonthsBetweenDates(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    return date2.Subtract(date1).Days / 30;
}


private int IntervalInMonthsBetweenDates(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    return ((date1.Year - date2.Year) * 12) + date1.Month - date2.Month;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking for `DateTime`s for the start and end of each month between two dates, not the difference between two dates in months.

Comment: @juharr May be. So his question is a little bit confusing, because he asks: My real question is HOW TO SEPARATE TWO DATES INTO THE MONTHS BETWEEN THEM?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sequece of `DateTime`s between the year and month of two given `DateTimes` where each beginning and end of the month is represented then you could do the following.

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> BeginEndOfEachMonthBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    DateTime start = from.AddDays(1 - from.Day);
    while(start <= to)
    {
        yield return start;
        yield return start.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
        start.AddMonths(1);
    }
}
```

But it would help to see how you plan to use this.

It sounds like you might want a query similar to this

```
SELECT 
    DatePart(year,Attendance_Date) As Year, 
    DatePart(month,Attendance_Date) As Month, 
    Count(*) As Attendance
FROM Attendances 
WHERE Attendance_Date Between @BeginDate And @EndDate
GROUP BY 
    DatePart(year,Attendance_Date), 
    DatePart(month,Attendance_Date)
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing something along the lines of (please forgive the brash approach I am still learning as I go and may be going about it in the wrong way), for each month in the period find the total attendances and print to excel

Comment: @user3408148 Then why not group by the year and month and use the date range you already created.

Comment: I think @juharr is right. And also it would be useful if you show an example of what you expect, since the question is a little bit confusing.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (DateTime i = fromDate; i.Date <= toDate.Date; i = i.AddMonths(1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.Month);
        }
```

Comment: What if the dates are : `2014/12/01` to `2015/02/28`

Comment: the dates will be 6 months apart, and any 6month period could be defined by the end user